# Test void method with JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit

Let's say I have a class like this one:

```
public class MyClass {

   private int var1;
   private int var2;

   public MyClass() {
      var1 = 0;
      var2 = 0;
   }

   public void setVariables() {
      var1 = 1;
      var2 = 1;
   }
```

I don't have any getter method inside my class.

Is there a way to test a void method like setVariables() with JUnit? How can I check its behavior without a direct access to variables value?

Comment: If there is no way to tell if the method has been called, I would  delete it as it doesn't do anything useful. So you don't need to test it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Deleting it would indeed solve the problem - no argument with that! ;-)

Comment: The method is used inside the class itself, it sets values of some JLabel and JButton. Because of it's part of a project about testing, maybe the only way is to include getter methods inside the class, but I don't know if this is a used practice with testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setVariables from your example is too simple to test. if your real method have any visible effects (non private state) then test that state. if state is private but has influence on other methods then test this method together with other methods. if you feel setVariables is so complex that it should be tested separately then test it. but remember: at this stage you are testing implementation, not the external contract - you will have to change your tests when you change implementation. if you want to do it, i suggest make var1 and var2 package visible - it's very convenient for tests. if they must stay private then the only solution is reflection and libraries like whiteBox

Comment: Since to change variables visibility and to add getter methods is about change the code under testing, I assume they are equivalent. Am I wrong?

Comment: i feel getter is adding functionality and unnecessary growing your code. changing variable visibility is making tests easier. many people also say 'don't change code for tests'. i disagree. i think code should be designed to be easily testable. TDD nicely enforce this approach

Answer (score 3):

Since this method does not have visible (from outside) side effect I would probably not test it.

Presumably, the fact that you set those variables has side effects on other methods. That's where you can test that those other methods execute as expected.

Comment: +1 Since there is no way to tell if it worked, it doesn't appear to matter if it worked or not.

Comment: It would matter if it worked or not, but it is more of a black box situation then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get access to the variables, write your test case in groovy which allows you to add a getter method dynamically, you could use some flavor of AOP (cglib, aspectJ) to test that the method gets called....